# Turn off whitespace-mode highlighting

Tags: whitespace, highlighting

I took the following from [this site](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/whitespace-mode.html).

`(progn
 ;; Make whitespace-mode with very basic background coloring for whitespaces.
  ;; http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/whitespace-mode.html
  (setq whitespace-style (quote (face spaces tabs newline space-mark tab-mark newline-mark )))
  ;; Make whitespace-mode and whitespace-newline-mode use “¶” for end of line char and “▷” for tab.
  (setq whitespace-display-mappings
        ;; all numbers are unicode codepoint in decimal. e.g. (insert-char 182 1)
        '(
          (space-mark 32 [183] [46]) ; SPACE 32 「 」, 183 MIDDLE DOT 「·」, 46 FULL STOP 「.」
          (newline-mark 10 [182 10]) ; LINE FEED,
          (tab-mark 9 [9655 9] [92 9]) ; tab
          )))`

The problem is `whitespace-mode` highlights every position where a space was. How can I disable the highlighting ?

Comment: `M-x whitespace-mode` toggles the mode on/off. `M-x customize-option whitespace-style` to customize which highlighting to use. `C-h f whitespace-mode` for more info. And consult the Emacs manual: `C-h r`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Useless-Whitespace.html):

> The kinds of whitespace visualized are determined by the list variable
>   `whitespace-style`. Individual elements in that list can be toggled on
>   or off in the current buffer by typing `M-x whitespace-toggle-options`.

You're setting `whitespace-style` with this code:

```
(setq whitespace-style (quote (face spaces tabs newline space-mark tab-mark newline-mark)))
```

Remove `spaces` to disable highlighting and remove `space-mark` to disable marking spaces with the dot.

Comment: Removing `spaces` solved the problem